# DS-2019 and J1 visa different 212(e) status

Tags: chinese-citizens, j1-visas, canadian-residents

I am a University Student in Canada working in the US next term, as I was preparing my documents for departure. I noticed that my DS-2019 said my country of permanent residence is China, though I am a Chinese citizen, I also have Canadian PR, does that matter?

I also noticed that the DS-2019 form said I am subject to 212(e) the two year residency requirement, but on my J1 visa it said that I am not subject to it. I'm not planning on working in the US after this internship but I was just wondering if this will cause me trouble at the border this time.

Does any of this matter or at the border they just check if your Visa is fake and if you have criminal intentions? I have never been to the US on a J1 before so I am really nervous. Thank you!

Comment: This probably fits better on [Expatriates.SE], but if I were you I would ask the school to give you a corrected DS-2019.